# Mysql Data type

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have question regrading data type in mysql.

I have a column in table called **status**

Which will have these values 0=pending, 1=active, 2=rejected, 3=suspend 4=approved 5=review

My question is what is the best data type to use.
Is

```
Char(1)
Tinyint(1)
SmallINT(1)
INT(1)
```

Which one of them is the best to use.

I been researching this to find but i'm not coming with any correct answer.

Please advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are the only 5 values ever allowed, then use a tinyint, which is a 1byte data type. That gives you a range of 0-255 (unsigned)/-128-+127 signed range.

Don't use chars to store numeric data. That's a text type.

Alternatively, you could use an [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) field, which would let you use your "friendly" names instead of plain numbers.

Comment: Thans for reply. I been told to avoid Enum.

Comment: @MarcB: Will it make any difference if a `TINYINT` or a `CHAR(1)` is used?

Comment: tinyint 1 is byte at all times, because it's just a number, char(1) can actually be more if you're storing utf-8/16 characters. You're storing numbers, so go with an int field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just not a big fan of having codes within a database table. What happens when a new status is added?

You can create a lookup (child) table called status.  Insert all the possible values for status, then setup a non-identifying relationship with the parent table.

If there is a special order (other than alphabetical) that status should be ordered by say in a drop down control, add a column that you can sort on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Because I have different status in each table which makes it hard to do this. e.g. I might have 0=No 1=Yes for active.

Comment: I will have same status also I will be writing status in different languages.

Comment: @Lalajee Not sure I follow - Do you mean you will have different status in each row or in each table?  Original question asked as part of one table.

Comment: Sorry. In each table. I have multiple tables where I have status columns. Which has numeric values it will be upto 9 numbers max.

Comment: Then I would do as Marc B recommends and use ENUM fields

Comment: Would that make query slow. I been reading online and most user say to avoid this. Would you recommend to use enum

Comment: Like I said, in a relational db, there is no need to use these types of constructs, here's another article that (unfortunately) illustrate some of the problems with ENUMs...  http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/